# Open a url on user web browser using nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, voip

I am building a simple VoIP app using asterisk-manager module on nodeJS. The asterisk server is installed on centos 7 (basic install) and is hosted on a virtual machine. The code below, listens for agent login event, and popups a url when it receives dtmf key:

```
var port = 5038,
    host = 'asteriskIP',
    username = 'popup',
    password = 'popup',
    open = require('open'),
    mysql = require('mysql'),
    ami = new require('asterisk-manager')(port, host, username, password, true);

ami.keepConnected();

//Mysql server connection pool
var pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: host,
    user: 'user',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'db'
});


ami.on('newstate', function (stateEvent) {
    var channelState = stateEvent.channelstate;
    if (channelState === '6') {
        return false;
    }

    /*
    Listen for new channel after agent login
    */
    ami.on('newchannel', function (e) {

        /* Check if caller id number is empty (This is necessary owning to new channel created as a result of
        DTMF. If this returns true, return false else execute mysql query.
        */

        if (e.calleridnum === '' && isNaN(e.calleridnum)) {
            return false;
        } else if (e.calleridnum !== '' && !isNaN(e.calleridnum)) {
            var callerId = e.calleridnum;
            sql = "INSERT INTO dtmf (caller_id) VALUES ?",
                values = [[callerId]];

            pool.query(sql, [values], function (error) {
                if (error) throw error;

            });

            /*
            Listen for DTMF on 'end' and update current caller table
            */
            ami.on('dtmf', function (evt) {
                var end = evt.end;
                if (end === 'Yes') {

                    var digit = evt.digit;
                    sql = `UPDATE dtmf SET caller_lang = ${digit}  WHERE caller_id = ?`,
                        values = [[callerId]];

                    pool.query(sql, [values], function (error) {
                        if (error) throw error;
                    });

                    /*
                    This piece of code retrieves DTMF code input and popsup 
                    a url in the agents browser window.
                    */
                    ami.on('bridge', function (evt) {
                        var state = evt.bridgestate;
                        if (state === 'Link') {
                            switch (digit) {
                                case '1':
                                    open('http://someurl?' + digit);
                                    break;
                                case '2':
                                    open('http://someurl?' + digit);
                                    break;
                                default:
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }

            });

        }
        return false;

    });
});
```

Everything works fine when I run this code on my mac. However, when I deployed the code to the virtual machine, it inserts and updates the database normally, but no url pops up in my browser. Please is there a way nodeJS app deployed on a virtual machine, can open a window on a users local browser? Thanks.

Comment: To be clear, you want the program running inside the virtual machine to be able to open a browser on the host OS, not the browser inside the VM?

Comment: Sorry for replying late and thanks for the question...yes please something like that paul

Answer (score 0):

For security reason there is no browser or OS that will let you pop up a browser window on someone else computer without first being connected.

For that i think you would have to build a client app for example a widget, service or browser extension that would be running on the person computer ...  This client could use Socket.io to listen and react to event happening on the Node.js end.

That could be one solution.

Comment: Thanks Simon. I will look into this.